# Custom Dialog with a listview crashing

Tags: android, listview, dialog, adapter

I've tried different things but things are still not 'going'

I have an activity. In this, when I press one of the options in the menu, I need to popup a dialog and in that dialog a listview of string values wich I get out of an string-arrays xml.

I've already deleted some code to clean it up but still no luck...

myList.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

my custom dialog

```
public class Selector extends Dialog {

String[] testArray;
protected Selector(Context context) {
    super(context);

    ListView lijstje = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.mylist);
    testArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies);
    Log.d("test",testArray[0]);//wich shows me the 1e string and it's working
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);
    lijstje.setAdapter(adapter);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, false);
    this.setContentView(v);

}

}
```

in my main activity I have I function

```
public void showPopup()
{       
    Selector test = new Selector(this);
    test.show();
}
```

when I put lijstje.setAdapter(adapter); in comment my app is not crashing but the dialog is very small  and empty

```
02-24 22:14:29.705: D/AndroidRuntime(28734): Shutting down VM
02-24 22:14:29.705: W/dalvikvm(28734): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4e1f8)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at be.veeteedev.OmzetterActivity.showPopup(OmzetterActivity.java:83)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at be.veeteedev.OmzetterActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(OmzetterActivity.java:59)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:163)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-24 22:14:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(28734):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use context in place of this.getContext()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will magically solve all you're problems, but in your Selector constructor you have the following assignment:

```
ListView lijstje = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.mylist);
```

Note how you are trying to find a View with a layout id. It should say something like `R.id.mylist` in stead. Currently it'll resolve to `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Also, you're doing `setContentView(...)` all the way at the end. If you're trying to inflate views from the mentioned layout file (`R.layout.mylist`), make sure you do this **after** having set the content view.

By the way, if you don't have a fancy layout for the dialog displaying a list, you can probably suffice with the default AlertDialog builder. [Have a read here, samples included](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList). For some help on custom dialogs, look [further down the bottom](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) of that same page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is your problem.  There is nothing to find the view by

```
ListView lijstje = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.mylist);
```

lijstje is null when called this way
lijstje is a layout not a view

also set content view should be before anything else

```
public class Selector extends Dialog {

String[] testArray;
protected Selector(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    ListView lijstje = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    testArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies);
    Log.d("test",testArray[0]);//wich shows me the 1e string and it's working
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);
    lijstje.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

mylist.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```